# How to install Vue on PHP project? (without cdn)

Tags: php, vue.js

I have an existing PHP project and am planning to install Vue using Vue-cli but not much is doing installation via modules.

Most tutorials I encounter are installing Vue in PHP projects via cdn and installing Vue on a Laravel framework.

Comment: There's not much info because there's not much to discuss. The output of Vue-cli setup is dist/ dir with static html and js files. You may want to use index.html as is because it contains dynamic urls on every build but otherwise it's a bunch of static files that you are free to integrate into your app the way you need

Comment: @EstusFlask Got any idea for installing vue 3 on pure PHP project without the need for `vue-cli` ?

Comment: First of all you need to specify your structure, are you using php as backend only(server logic)? or you are also rendering pages using php ? Do you want to use both vue and php on the front end together ?

Comment: So what Laravel installer gives is a pre bundle with Vue. You need to understand that PHP is backend and Vue is frontend both are independent of each other, it doesn't matter whether you place them in same repo or separate. You just need to figure out the communication between the both. Frontend language is not something you install on a backend language

Comment: I would recommend to follow a Vue setup independent of PHP and then make them communicate with each other. Although this also takes one to learn about HTTP origin, referrer, .etc as well.

Comment: @Shulz It's unclear what's your goal. "installing" presumes that you use tools to build vue app. vue-cli, vite, etc are such tools. They provide you with a preconfigured usable project setup that uses Webpack or Rollup bundler. Laravel uses the same in-house thing. "Vue CDN" is a general term for loading Vue as a script and using `window.Vue`, it's primarily used with real CDN but you can copy a script locally in case that's how you want it to do, you won't be able to use .vue files this way as they need a build tool.

Comment: The way I wanted to use Vue is that I can call vue's component on different page from .php to make it more clearer. @Cerceis
With regards to routing.. note sure about this one.